# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, overriding

I tried to override a protected method in python and I got this exception:

if float(rMontant) >= float(self.__decouvert_autorise):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

this is my code:

```
class Compte(object):
    def __init__(self, numero, nom_titulaire, solde):
        self.__numero = numero
        self.__nomTitulaire = nom_titulaire
        self.__solde = solde

    def _retirer(self, rMontant):
        if self.__solde >= rMontant:
            self.__solde -= rMontant
            print("bien retirer")


class CompteCourant(Compte):
    def __init__(self, numero, nom_titulaire, solde):
        super().__init__(numero, nom_titulaire, solde)
        self.__decouvert_autorise = 0

    def setDecouvertAutorise(self, decouvert_autorise):
        self.__decouvert_autorise = decouvert_autorise

    def _retirer(self, rMontant):
        if float(rMontant) >= float(self.__decouvert_autorise):
            return "plus que le solde autorisé"
        else:
            self._retirer(rMontant)
            return "ok"


p = CompteCourant(1425, "azer", 8000)
p.setDecouvertAutorise(1000)
print(p._retirer(500))
```

Comment: `self._retirer(rMontant)` isn't calling the superclass `_retirer`.

Comment: You programmed a recursion inside the child class and `rMontant` is not modified , so the maximum recursion depth is reached.